# PHP SQL Table Creation and Maintenance

Tags: php

What are some good recommendations for managing SQL tables?  I want to move away from writing and editing sql tables manually, and therefore was wondering what was peoples standpoint.

I been playing with the idea of creating an up and down function in my conroller class using Kohana's ORM.  For example.

```
Class books_Controller{
   static function up(){
     //create sql database tables;
   }
   static function down(){
     // delete cuurent db table
   }
}
```

Then I call to up to create the tables and down to remove.

```
books_Controller::up();
books_Controller::down();
```

Thats great except when setting up a new server it can become a hastle creating and updating an 'init.php' file.  Also sites new specific things on a per site basis.

### Proposal

I've thought about creating a simple online php terminal.  For example, I could visit domain.com/terminal, enter username and password and be able to eval input.  From there I could bring up and down only specific sql tables along with other maintenance.  Pros? Cons?

I don't hate sql, but I find it troublesome to manage/update up to date sql files.  Also abstractions are near impossible in sql.

Comment: I'll take a look ;) Also what do you think about a php terminal? Is that potential a bad idea(ignoring the security aspect).

Comment: php terminal? no sense for me

Comment: To much scope for debate here, demonstrated already by the comment exchange in Kerin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL abstractions already exist, but they are oriented toward allowing the same language to interact with multiple flavors of SQL, rather than eliminating it entirely.  You might check out PearDB (http://pear.php.net/DB) if that would suit your purposes.

To wit, though, the kind of thing you are talking about isn't really possible - SQL is not very complicated, and if you implemented a series of functions flexible enough to encapsulate SQL's functionality you would only succeed at creating... an abstraction layer for SQL that is just as complicated and with no vendor support.  This is very much like setting your car on fire to prevent it being stolen.

With regards to your terminal idea, PHPPGAdmin and PHPMyAdmin do this already for PostgreSQL and MySQL, respectively.  In terms of security, both utilities allow (and by default, PHPPGAdmin requires) that the user come from a specific IP range.  A purely username-password authentication would open your database up to brute force attacks directly, which is a Bad Thing.

Comment: Obviously brute force attacks are a bad thing, but doesn't that theoretically imply that my google, stackoverflow, etc. accounts  are also just as insecure?

Comment: Looking at this page, Pear just appears to be a PDO wrapper.  http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-execute.php It does provide additional functionality, but it definitely doesn't appear to be a ORM.

Comment: Your google, stack overflow, etc accounts are indeed just as insecure.  The difference is that someone cracking the password to your personal account should not compromise customer or other business data, and because of this there is generally far less incentive for it to be cracked.  Indeed, preventing a server from being vulnerable to the same attacks that user accounts are is a major part of any security scheme.

Comment: The reason that nobody uses ORM to deal with SQL is because, as I have said, SQL itself is simple.  There is no benefit to abstracting it beyond compatibility between SQL versions. ORM techniques are only going to make your SQL programming more esoteric, which will be to the detriment of anyone who has to work with your code.

Comment: So is Kohana's ORM considered bad practice?  Because the `has_many`, `belongs_to`, and `has_one` ORM implementations seem pretty common.

Comment: Kohana definitely seems like a solution in search of a problem.  Abstracting SQL access in this manner will only ever be helpful if finely-tuned performance is not an issue.  It will also make troubleshooting a nightmare.  And it still, as I tire of saying, makes your code needlessly difficult to parse for anyone who isn't already familiar with it.

Comment: What is your standpoint on couchdb vs mongodb then?  Also do you really mean to say 'solution in search of a problem'?  Because it seems a gazillion times more intuitive to me.

Comment: CouchDB and MongoDB are different database systems, and beyond the scope of this question.  Yes, I said exactly what I meant to.  It may be more intuitive to you but for work with a database in which query optimization matters you aren't going to be well-served with an abstraction.  Because of this, straight SQL (which is itself extremely simple) will always be the choice of professional developers of SQL applications.

Comment: I feel points like the ones are important, and often ignored until the end of a project.  ORM vs SQL actually matters whether people want to talk about it.  Well if they are going to close the question someone deserves credit!  Thanks for talkin'